# SAS: dynamically specify dataset name in hash object in proc fcmp function

Tags: sas

I would like to specify the name of the dataset as an input parameter to the fcmp function that is declaring the hash object:

```
    function somefunction(dsn $, k1 $, k2 $, k3 $, k4 $);
      declare hash h(dataset: "work.someDatasetName");
      *declare hash h(dataset: dsn);
      rc = h.defineKey('k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4');
      rc = h.defineData('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6');
      rc = h.definedone();
      rc = h.find();
```

The commented line declare hash h(dataset: dsn) will not work. The declare function requires a literal or character variable. How can transfer the value of dsn from the function arguments into the hash object declaration statement?

The error that I get is:

163           declare hash h(dataset: dsn);
___
22
202
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a quoted string.
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.

---

[SAS Documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/lecompobjref/p00ilfw5pzcjvtn1nfya9863fozd.htm#n059t1gb0pk3fyn1xj0ps2vhvs4n)

argument_tag:value

specifies the information that is used to create an instance of the hash object.
There are five valid hash object argument and value tags:
dataset: 'dataset_name <(datasetoption)>'

Specifies the name of a SAS data set to load into the hash object.
The name of the SAS data set can be a literal or character variable. The data set name must be enclosed in single or double quotation marks. Macro variables must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

Comment: Do you get any other errors in the log before that?

Comment: Looks like something that would be more easily made as macro instead of a function.

Comment: You might get some partial dynamics by referencing a VIEW in the FUNCTION and then modifying the view before the step that calls the function.

Comment: Or use the RUN_MACRO statement inside PROC FCMP to call a macro which recompiles the FCMP function each time it's called with the relevant dataset name.

Comment: @ChrisJ The function will be called many times (millions). Thus, I am concerned about the effectiveness of this approach. Do you think that declaring the hash object outside of the function and passing in the hash object would be more effective? Then, I could see a setup macro being used.

Comment: For a suggestion of way to do the analysis you need you could post the bigger picture of what analysis you are trying to do.  As it stands this question is just about an issue with implementing one little step in the analysis.  Perhaps there is a way to do what you want that does not need FCMP to support dynamic dataset names for defining hash objects.

Comment: @Tom Much previous consideration has been given to whether or not to use macros or proc fcmp.  The big picture is to store probability distribution generation information within datasets (possibly quite large) and then be able to look up (in an efficient manner) the information so that appropriate generated values can be returned.

Comment: It was hoped the the dataset that was holding the information for the hash object could be parameterized for testing variations in the stored data.  This [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwio_MKh99T_AhU3nGoFHVYxCrcQFnoECBwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.sas.com%2Fresources%2Fpapers%2Fproceedings%2Fproceedings%2Fsugi31%2F241-31.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1AgoQcvr3O45mSlRNTsdkO&opi=89978449) illustrates doing that with the use of a hash object within a data step.  Unfortunately, it looks like it cannot be done for a hash object with FCMP

Answer (score 2):

I think this limit is documented.

- PROC FCMP Hash and Hash Iterator Language Elements

  - DECLARE Statement: Hash Object and Hash Iterator Object

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lecompobjref/n098ljby3kptf0n1caygy0dipu2r.htm#p17vi6r6c5zhmen1aqtyxoml73os

> The name of the SAS data set must be a literal. A literal data set
> name must be enclosed in single or double quotation marks.

Comment: Yes, that is point of my post. I am trying to figure out a way to get around this limitation (if possible). I tried functions that convert to literals but they did not work. I get that it just might not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tom, it is not possible to pass a string variable argument to the declaration of a hash object within an fcmp function (in the same way that you can for a data step hash object).

That said, there may well be an alternative (and better performing) lookup solution.

You mention that this lookup function is to be 'called' millions of times:-

- Do you mean called from within a data step - ie where the data step is iterating through (millions of) observations from a 'master' dataset and each observation has variables for the dataset name and other input parameters listed in your example fcmp function?
- How many of these lookup tables are there?
- How large are these lookup tables? How many unique values per dataset? Can they all fit into memory?
- It would appear from your example fcmp function that these lookup tables have either the same data structure, or at least the same key and data variables required to satisfy the lookup?

Depending on your answers to the above, data step hash object(s), with the addition of some macro code, may well satisfy your requirement - either pre-loaded before iterating through your 'master' dataset or loaded on the fly.

Or there maybe an alternative lookup approach that is more appropriate for your particular need. Difficult to say without more information.

EDIT:

A small number of lookup tables could  (depending on size) be preloaded in your data step - ie before you start iterating thru your master dataset with, for example, do until(eof_master) code.

I would then use if/then logic (or select/when) within the do until loop to lookup values (in the relevant hash object) based on the incoming dataset name (from your master).

The pre-loading of hash objects will likely more than compensate for the if/then or select/when.

NB There is no need to use macro code and remember to add a stop stmt after the do until loop.

Comment: I believe that the answer to your questions is yes. A datastep will be used to generate millions of random variables from the distributions described by the data in the hash table. They generally have the same data structure. So I would be interested in an outline of how to achieve this pre-loading via macro code.

Comment: How many dataset names - ie lookup tables - are there?

Comment: The number of look up tables is limited. One lookup table maps to 1 random variable.  I have 4-5 look up tables.